# Pantone color reference with 2X

Tags: terminology, pantone

In the plastic industry, what's the meaning of 2X after a Pantone reference ?

```
802 C2X compared to 802 C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Pantone Website](http://www.pantone.com/help/?t=Double-Impression-(2X)-PANTONE-Colors)

> 2X = double impression, usually referred to as a 'dry trap', where a
>   color is printed, dried back, and then overprinted a second time to
>   produce a more intense color.

So adding more saturation when printing.

However the website does mention that they have discontinued adding this to their system.

> 2X colors were deleted from the PANTONE MATCHING SYSTEM products back
>   in 2000. The reason for this is because they were rarely used, and
>   caused unnecessary confusion when they were specified.